# No viable overloaded operator[] for type std::vector<ComparisonPair>

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to iterate through a `vector` of `ComparisonPair` `struct`s. However, I get an error

```
no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'std::vector<ComparisonPair>'
```

This is the code

```
std::vector<ComparisonPair>::iterator i;
for (i = comparisons.begin(); i!= comparisons.end(); ++i)
```

{

std::cout << comparison[I].name;

}

comparisons being a `vector` of `ComparisonPair`s
I have a header file with the `struct` in it as simple as

```
struct ComparisonPair
{
std::string name;
int count;
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't even use `[]`, so it's clearly not the one giving you the error. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This works like a charm though: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad60a627c8c5e753

Comment: Oh, for some reason thought iterator was a number rather than similar to a pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time writing C++ so wrongly assumed iterators worked as a special type of integer to hold different sizes. They're used similar to pointers which fixes the error.